# Several unknown attributes in AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, flutter

I have a working flutter project written using Android Studio. In my AndrodiManifest.xml, several of the tags are underlined and when I hover over them it says unknown attribute. According to the documentation, those are valid tags. The consequence of these so called invalid tags is that launcher icon gets installed to the app tray but not to the Home Screen. How do I fix these? Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sevocab">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33"/>

   <application
        android:label="SE Vocab"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is a screenshot of the underlined tags

[image: This is a screenshot of the underlined tags]

Output of flutter doctor

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.7.11 on channel stable at /Users/lk/programs/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f72efea43c (3 days ago), 2023-04-11 11:57:21 -0700
    • Engine revision 1a65d409c7
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/lk/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Pixel 2 XL (mobile) • 806KPDT1944522 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • macOS (desktop)     • macos          • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)        • chrome         • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.49

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this please?

Navigate to the below mentioned `locations` on your machine and perform a `cleanup` of the same.

Assuming you are using `MacOSX`

```
/Users/<user>/.gradle/caches/
/System/Library/Caches
```

Also, if this doesn't work then open `Android studio`, go to `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried them out but I still face the same issue. Now, I can't even build the code because it is still looking for files in the cache instead of rebuilding them. How do I fix this? 

/Users/lk/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b9774fa1cbd0e12109dbe12171ad1f46/transformed/jetified-play-services-base-18.0.1/res/color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml:5: error: resource not found

Comment: I fixed the build issue by deleting /Users/<username>/.grade and forcing gradely reinstallation